# How to get right result of preg_match() in this case

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to get result from `preg_match()` in this case.

```
$regex = '/[A-Z][a-z][0-9]/i';
```

What is the right code to get result below.

```
preg_match($regex, 'phpversion7')  //return false

preg_match($regex, 'Phpversion7')  //return true

preg_match($regex, 'Phpversion')  //return false

preg_match($regex, 'R1985y2528')  //return true

preg_match($regex, 'R19852528')  //return false
```

Comment: You have to be more clear, what *is* the result you want, what have you tried?

Comment: @Nytrix How about this.

Comment: You should probably still tell us what `$regex` is (assuming you ment it as a variable)... Second, on what condition do you want a result? Please try to answer the question yourself with the info you are giving, you are not giving much.

Answer (score 0):

Simple asign a variable to each  **preg_match ()**  statement which will store a boolean

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear what you want, but I guess you need something like:

```
/^[A-Z](?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]+$/
```

This regex matches strings that begin with a capital letter and contain at least one letter and at leat one digit.

**Explanation:**

```
/               : regex delimiter
  ^             : start of string
  [A-Z]         : a capital letter
  (?=.*[a-z])   : lookahead, a small letter must be present in the string
  (?=.*\d)      : lookahead, a digit must be present in the string
  [a-zA-Z\d]+   : the whole string must contains only letters and digits.
  $             : end of string
/               : regex delimiter
```